# Porting contiki on MSP430 using IAR

Tags: compiler-errors, porting, msp430, iar, contiki

I am using a MSP-EXP430F5438 board and was trying to port contiki on it using the source code(contiki 2.6) through IAR.

I am getting the following errors-

```
Error[Pe020]: identifier "CC2520_IRQ_VECTOR" is undefined E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 50

Error[Pe661]: expected an integer constant E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 50

Error[Pe020]: identifier "DIR" is undefined E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 67

Error[Pe020]: identifier "CC2520_CSN_PIN" is undefined E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 67

Error[Pe137]: expression must be a modifiable lvalue E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 67

Error[Pe020]: identifier "CC2520_VREG_PIN" is undefined E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 68

Error[Pe137]: expression must be a modifiable lvalue E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 68

Error[Pe020]: identifier "CC2520_RESET_PIN" is undefined E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 69

Error[Pe137]: expression must be a modifiable lvalue E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 69

Error[Pe020]: identifier "CC2520_FIFOP_PIN" is undefined E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 71

Error[Pe137]: expression must be a modifiable lvalue E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 71

Error[Pe020]: identifier "CC2520_FIFO_PIN" is undefined E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 72

Error[Pe137]: expression must be a modifiable lvalue E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 72

Error[Pe020]: identifier "CC2520_CCA_PIN" is undefined E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 73

Error[Pe137]: expression must be a modifiable lvalue E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 73

Error[Pe020]: identifier "CC2520_SFD_PIN" is undefined E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 74

Error[Pe137]: expression must be a modifiable lvalue E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\cpu\msp430\cc2520-arch.c 74

Error while running C/C++ Compiler

Error[Pe020]: identifier "CC2520_FIFOP_IS_1" is undefined E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\core\dev\cc2520.c 201

Fatal Error[Pe035]: #error directive: CC2520_CONF_SYMBOL_LOOP_COUNT needs to be set!!! E:\PS-1\contiki-2.6\core\dev\cc2520.c 361

Error while running C/C++ Compiler
```

Do you think a header file might be missing in the source code?

Regards

Comment: If more files are added to the IAR workspace error[e46] shows up

Answer (score 0):

To run contiki in IAR there are few steps require: (i) you need to have the license for IAR (TI platform specific radio) that you are using. However you can download it from IAR website for msp430 (size or time limited), (ii). Have to find an equivalent function in the IAR toolchain libraries for example . Write your own clean function that performs the same purpose as the original library routine. (iii) Edit (Makefile.common) the platform specific makefile for example inside contiki/platform/sky Makefile.common have a look into line 17. I am assuming that you are using windows platform as IAR does n't support Linux distributions (ex. Ubuntu). (IV) special care for some c files such as (ip64.c from apps/ip64 uip-icmp6.c from core/net and uip-nd6.c) compiler 'll arise some error you must need to know which function to enable and disable depending on your applications.